# Element won't log in

Tags: networking

Some weeks ago, an ubuntu upgrade crashed. I made a backup of my home directory and then wiped my hard drive. On the "new" system, I copied over my personal directory, but had to rebuild my installed apps from scratch.

I recently re-installed Element and it found it's folder, but it won't log in to the matrix server.  It says

> Connectivity to the server has been lost.

> Sent messages will be stored until your connection has returned

It does not reconnect on it's own and I can't figure out what setting needs to be changed to make it connect.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to convince it to re-connect without blowing away it's folder?
- What will I lose if I do blow away this folder, (or should I just do it)?
- **Where** is this folder anyway?

I am on Ubuntu 22.10 (and was previously on Ubuntu studio on whatever version was one-behind-current in August).

I downloaded Element from the Ubuntu store and it is version 1.11.23 and is a flatpak.

Comment: how does this relate to ubuntu? read [ask] then [edit] accordingly

Comment: I have hopefully addressed your concerns, but if not, do you have suggestions for a more appropriate forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to bin the flatpack and install via apt using the instructions on element's website: https://element.io/download#linux-details

Unfortunately, because I'd run the flatpak program in the mean time, it had to wipe my folder which has consequences for reading old encrypted messages.

The real answer here appears to be to avoid flatpak stuff.